# How to send app_name,method_name url namespaces in Django

Tags: python, django, url

I'm trying to get the hang of Django URL namespaces. But I can't find any examples or documentation.

Here is what I have tried.

foo.urls

```
from django.urls import path, include
from Foo.Views import FooView


app_name ="Foo"

urlpatterns = [
path('', referansView.referans_listele , name="foo"),
path('create/', olusturView.referans_olustur, name="foo_create"),
]
```

foo.html

```
<a class="btn btn-success"
   href="{% url '{{foo}}:{{foo_create}}' %}?r=Foo:  {{request.resolver_match.url_name}}">
```

fooview.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from Foo.models import FooModels

def foo_create(request):
    result ={"Foo":"Foo"}
    return render(request,"referanslar.html", result)
```

What I want is to be able to browse to /foo/X

Comment: Using `foo` everywhere has made your example very confusing. It looks as if you want `{% url 'Foo:foo_create' %}` (`Foo` with a capital `F` because you have `app_name = 'Foo'`).

Comment: Thank you for asking. Actually I want to write dynamically  this code ({% url 'Foo:foo_create%}') . How can  make  dynamically  {%url {{foo}}:{{foo_create}} %} with context variables in django template

Comment: As I said, your example code is confusing. You don't have `foo` or `foo_create` in the template context, only `'Foo'`. Perhaps you can use the [`add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#add) filter, e.g. `{% url foo|add:':'|add:foo_create %}`.

Comment: I am so sory. I edit the view in Django Project. This code is like below                                from django.shortcuts import render
from Foo.models import FooModels

def foo_create(request):
    result ={"Foo":"Foo_appName","fooView":"fooView"  }
    return render(request,"referanslar.html", result)

Comment: Then you would do `{% url Foo|add:':'|add:fooView %}`. However, it might be simpler to pass {'fooView': 'Foo:fooView'}` to the template and do `{% url fooView %}`. Or you could pass the reversed url to the template with `{'foourl': reverse('Foo:fooView')}`, then use `{{ foourl }}`.

Comment: Thank you for asking @Alasdair. How do make refering this code  ( {'fooView': 'Foo:fooView'})  variable object  In Django Template ? For example {% url '{{Foo}}:{{fooView}}' %} can make it or can not making for variable object in Django Template

Comment: You don't use `{{ }}` inside a `{% url %}` tag. Just use the variable name. I covered the `{'fooView': 'Foo:fooView'}` case in my last comment - use  `{% url fooView %}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the urls in main site urls like

```
path('foo/', include('foo.urls')),
```